# Meteor Angular forkjoin for server side data initialization

Tags: typescript, meteor, rxjs, observable, angular-meteor

I'm trying to use the RxJS `Observable.forkjoin` method to synchronize my serverside created fake data but it never triggers the subscription if I try to use them with `MeteorObservable.Collection<any>.insert` methods.

If I try to use the same with "original" angular `Observable` like `observableBatchTest.push(Observable.from([i]));` there is no problem and the subscription is triggered fine.

Here's a small minimal example of the existing problem:

```
function initFakeChats(numberOfChats: number): Observable<{}[]> {

 let observableBatch = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfChats; i++) {
    var data = {
      messages: Fake.word(),
      name: Fake.word(),
    };
    observableBatch.push(Chats.insert(data));
  }
  return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch);
}

export function fakeAll() {

  let chatIds = initFakeChats(2).subscribe(
    fakeChatIds => {
      console.dir('Finished Fake Chats');
      console.dir(fakeChatIds);
      return fakeChatIds;
    },
    error => {
      console.dir(error);
    });
}
```

Is there a special meteor way to reach something similar like that? For example dynamic nested `Meteor.call`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the problem now - related to this topic https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-rxjs/issues/25 .

The `MeteorObservable` subscriptions never fire a complete event - because of that there is no possibility to fire a `forkjoin` (which needs all inner observables fired completed).

`combineLatest` works instead - I just have now to workout to get the recognition of something like "completed" (could use the array size of a fake object loop to check if the subscription callbacks are "completed"), before run next fake creation tasks.